# problems with my mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i have this query:

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ = (SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` = (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb)))
```

But when I run it I'm getting this error:

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I don't know what is in my query wrong.

Example how `lm_Schwellwert` looks:

```
Typ     Schwellwert
Computer    78
```

Example how `lm_Artikel` looks:

```
Index   Artikelbezeichnung  Status  Bestand     Lieferant    Typ
1           HP Elitebook        OK      19         HP         Computer
```

Example how `lm_Warenkorb` looks:

```
Index
11
1
```

Comment: as it says - your subquery should return only one result, while now it's returning 2 results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where condition could run only aginst one vale (so x=y and so on)
In your case, your subquery

`(SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE`Index`= (SELECT DISTINCT`Index`FROM lm_Warenkorb))`

is returning more than one row and this cause an error.

Try to modify your query as follow

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ IN (SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb)))
```

The `IN` operator will help you, since accept a set of values and return true if `Typ` is equal to one of those

Comment: this gives me a bigger error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT DISTINCT Index FROM lm_Warenkorb))) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `in` will help you:

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ in (SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` in (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb)))
```

you can also use  aggregate function `min` for example:

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ in (SELECT min(Typ) FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` in (SELECT min(`Index`) FROM lm_Warenkorb)))
```

Comment: @Pgr456 You can try second solution.

Comment: the second solution gives me this syntax error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE Index in (SELECT DISTINCT Index FROM lm_Warenkor at line 3`

Comment: ok youre querie is working so far but it gives me only one result it should get me 3 results in my test setup

Comment: @Pgr456 3 results? You have only one row in `lm_Schwellwert` and 2 rows in `lm_Artikel`. Can you show as what do you expect?

Comment: those were examples got the solution from DonCallisto thanks for youre help

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ = (SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel 
              WHERE `Index` in (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb)))
```

because u have two values in index

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb
```

This sub query returns two rows.. it should have only one as you are using an equal to sign..

try this:

```
SELECT Schwellwert
FROM lm_Schwellwert
WHERE (Typ = (SELECT  Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` in (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb)) limit 1)
```

Comment: gives me a syntax error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` in (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkor' at line 3`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
Select 
    lm_Schwellwert.Schwellwert
From lm_Schwellwert
Left join lm_Schwellwert as r 
    on r.Typ = (SELECT Typ FROM lm_Artikel WHERE `Index` = (SELECT DISTINCT `Index` FROM lm_Warenkorb))
Where r.id is not null  
group by lm_Schwellwert.Typ
```

Comment: this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'r.id' in 'where clause'` is the result

Comment: use primary key instead of r.id use r.table_primary_key

Comment: ok inserted my primary key and getting this: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`